# Data Table and Layout combination, CSS or tables?

Tags: css, html-table

I am implementing a schedule application that displays activities as rows and time shifts as columns.  It allows users to group activities and days, spanning rows and columns.  I posted a mock up at http://www.volunteeryourself.com/sch.htm.   Would you do this data table/layout as a CSS or table?  I can make either one work, just not sure which is better.

Given some of the features and the need to allow the user to add/manipulate items, I think CSS would work best.

Sorry if this is not the type of question to post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll say what I said earlier, If you are trying to achieve the image above the tables with the table content then DIV's and CSS will be less hassle.

If you are laying out pure tabular data then use tables, but tables are normally harder to style and get positioning etc right with.

Answer (score 0):

it's tabular data, therefore you should use tables.

CSS *can* be used for this, (or I should say, a combination of divs/spans etc), but you would be creating unnecessary work for yourself.

By all means use CSS to style the table, but the bulk of the layout should be done using semantic table markup.